# Manuscript recovered from crashed plane about human-insect hive in Siberia

Tags: story-identification, hybrid

It's **not** Frank Herbert's *[Hellstrom's Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellstrom%27s_Hive)*.

Cannot find old 20+ years paperback scifi novel about insect-human hive in Siberia. A man follows his brother to work in a research station in Siberia. His brother looks after the (sledge?) dogs in the secret facility. The hive is destroyed and man leaves on a plane together with (daughter?) of the scientist who bred the hybrids. The plane crashes and we do not find out what happens to author.

Comment: I notice that you're using some grammar patterns characteristic of Russian. Was this book in English or another language?

Comment: Stories do not need to be in English to be on-topic, but it's helpful to identify the language as it helps to narrow down the possibilities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like *[Genesis Five](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16034233-genesis-five)* (1968) by Henry Wilson Allen. It's been a long time, but this is what I remember: the time is the future USSR and the main character is half Tartar or half Mongol. He is assigned to the northern top-secret Genesis 5 project where his brother is working because the government is worried about just what is going on there. It turns out a Chinese scientist is genetically engineering the ultimate Soviet Man - half-insect, half-human. Somehow the hybrids escape & destroy the project. The MC and the scientist's daughter escape by air but crash in the wilderness; the MC records everything that happened in a journal to warn future generations on the dangers of genetic engineering.

Comment: Yup, that is the one, thanks very much. I thought it had the Tartar bit, but because I could not be sure of the exact affiliation I left that bit out of the question. Lost my copy in the mess, and wanted to buy another. Cheers muchly.